# Convert a horizontal menu into a vertical one

Tags: html, css, navbar

how can i make this horizontal-menu into a vertical one, so that when you scale the window to a specific width, toggle popps, by clicking onto which the menu appears verticaly.

I tried to make it with overflow hidden, however it doesn't seem to work

My nav HTML Code:

```
<nav>

        <div id ="wrapper">

            <div class="logo" >

                <h2> Navbar </h2>


            </div>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Pricings </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Blog </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="exclusive"> Contact </a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="toggle">
                <div id="one" class="line"> </div>
                <div id="two" class="line"> </div>
                <div id="three" class="line"> </div>
            </div>



        </div>

    <!--    
        <div id="place">
                <ul id="resize">
                    <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Pricings </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Blog </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            -->
    </nav>
```

The entire code: https://jsfiddle.net/20ynL31t/1/

Comment: Add the relevant styles to your question

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `width: 100%` from the `li` element like the following:

```
#wrapper ul li {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the menu to be a full screen, and here is the link : https://codepen.io/mk_dev/pen/pOqwpo

```
<input type="checkbox" id="op" autocomplete="off">
```

The easiest way would be to use a checkbox which on checking opens the menu and displays the menu links.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```css
#wrapper ul li {
display: block;
}
```